# AngularJS: Template-added ng-click does not fire

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I dynamically added ng-click within my directive's template, but it does not seem to fire (or have been compiled by angular) at all. Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/srph/f162ca4c9b4f12e7c586) of my files.

Although I have problems with the scope, I think the *current* problem isn't with the scopes. But feel free to include whatever problem may arise with my current scope options.

I have this structure in my HTML:

```
main element | MainCtrl
    | directive 1 | ss-pagination
        | directive 1.1 | ss-pagination-previous
        | directive 1.2 | ss-pagination-next
```

I have 3 directives, 1 being a parent to 2 directives having the `ng-click` included in their template. The reason is, I have a main pagination directive which contains settings | functions for the pagination. The other two is used as next | previous buttons.

The controller code style seems to be different from the directive given the fact that I am currently refactoring.

Comment: Could you please set up [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/) reproducing this issue, so that we can have a better look at it? Thanks!

Comment: Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MiIYuKUVErL83d0pgwg9?p=preview), sir.

Comment: I will have a look at it right now, but have you had a look at my answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I found what the problem is. Change your `pagination-prev.directive.js` to use `controllerAs`, so that you can call the controller's function `goToPreviousPage` from the view, like this:

```
(function(angular, undefined) {
  function paginationPrevious() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      require: '^ssPagination',
      template: getTemplate,
      controller: 'PaginationPreviousCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'prevCtrl'
    };

    function getTemplate(element, attrs) {
      return [
        '<div ng-transclude ',
        'ng-click="prevCtrl.goToPreviousPage()">',
        '</div>'
      ].join('');
    }
  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('ssPaginationPrevious', paginationPrevious);
})(angular);
```

Comment: You're right! However, it tells me that a function named goToPage (which I made from the parent directive, pagination) is undefined. How do I access the parent's "this"?

Comment: @KierBorromeo mmm sorry, but you can't do it like that... If you set the `require` like this: `require:['ssPaginationPrevious','^ssPagination']` then inside the `link` function you could have access to both controllers, but the controller's directive itself doesn't inherit the parent's controller.

Comment: @KierBorromeo my current answer solves the original question, therefore I think that you should mark it as accepted. However, I understand that this still doesn't solve your main problem, so why don't you start a new question so that I can keep helping you there? thanks!